# how can remove name of app in android studio

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-studio

try to remove my app name but cant do it .

this is my XML main layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:background="#FF000000"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

this is my string resource :

```
<resources>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="section_format">Hello World from section: %1$d</string>
</resources>
```

and Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.er.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

so i do every way to delete name of app but at last always show project name . like this  :

[image]

Don,t want show any text here! how can i do ? how can remove this!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your string.xml, add this line

```
<string name="app_name">your_project_name</string> // write nothing  if you don't want to show anything
```

In you manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" // add this line
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**Or,**

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:label="" // add this line
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```